# convert Codable to Json (Dictionary) Swift

Tags: swift, codable

How can I convert Codable to Json Dictionay its a nested struct

struct one

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name = "siddhant"
    var age = 12
    var topInt = ["1","2","3"]
    var moreDetails = MoreDetails()
}
```

struct Two

```
struct MoreDetails: Codable {
    var image = "ImageUrl"
}
```

I need out put as a Json when I convert this to Json it just convert me the struct one not the 2nd struct

```
   do {
        let sid = try JSONEncoder().encode(users)

        let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: sid, options: []) as? [String: Any]


        print(dict)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

current output which is wrong:

```
(["name": siddhant, "topInt": <__NSArrayI 0x2831a1c20>(1,2,3),           
"moreDetails": {
image = ImageUrl;
}, "age": 12])
```

I want output like

```
{
"name": "siddhant",
"topInt": ["1", "2", "3"],
"moreDetails": {
    "image": "ImageUrl"
},
"age": 12
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and show your users declaration and the expected result

Comment: Shouldn't the json result be an array of dictionaries `as? [[String: Any]]`?

Comment: Your expected output it is not a valid json string

Comment: no normal dictionary

Comment: give me one sec

Comment: If you want to moreDetails be an array you just have to change your variable to `var moreDetails: [MoreDetails] = [MoreDetails(), MoreDetails()]`

Comment: check now please

Comment: you added a single user json sample. Note that `sid` is your JSON data. All you need is to convert it to string `String(data: sid, encoding: .utf8)!`

Comment: yea its single only

Comment: If you need include new line as well you need to encode using `outputFormatting` `.prettyPrinted`

Comment: `let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        let sid = try encoder.encode(users)
        print(String(data: sid, encoding: .utf8)!)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I want in [string: Any].but this  print(String(data: sid, encoding: .utf8)!). gives me String

Comment: There is no such thing as a json dictionary, json is a string. If you want to convert your struct to a dictionary maybe you can try reflection using `Mirror`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson {
"name": "siddhant",
"topInt": ["1", "2", "3"],
"moreDetails": {
    "image": "ImageUrl"
},
"age": 12
} I have to. post this in api in raw formate

Comment: I don't think you have an api that require a [String: Any] dictionary but if there is then json is completely irrelevant for this. I believe the last comment from @LeoDabus gives you the correct solution.

Comment: in alamofire we send [String: Any] in params right ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension on Encodable so that you can use it for all elements that conform to `Encodable` protocol

```swift
extension Encodable {

  var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
  }

}
```

In your case if the model is `user` of type `User`

```swift
guard let userDict = user.dictionary else { return }
```

Comment: I user there is one more model named moreDetails, the more details is not getting converted

Comment: I don't get moreDetails as Json

Comment: @Leo.  If you are looking to see the json data, then you can use like this:  let user1 = User()
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user1) else { return  }
      
    let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print(json)

Comment: can I send  String in params of alamofire ?

Answer (score 2):

what I did now is

```
let users = User()

let staticJson = ["name": users.name,
              "age": users.age,
              "topInt": users.topInt,
              "moreDetails": ["image": users.moreDetails.image]] as? [String: Any]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what is your desired result. Following your code:

```
    struct User: Codable {
    var name = "siddhant"
    var age = 12
    var topInt = ["1","2","3"]
  var moreDetails = MoreDetails()


  var dictionaryJson: [String : Any] {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encoder.encode(self), options: .allowFragments)) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
  }

}

struct MoreDetails: Codable {
    var image = "ImageUrl"
}

do {

  let users = User()
  let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(users)
  let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!

  print(jsonString)
  print("\n")
  print(users.dictionaryJson)

  print("\n")
  print("Getting the var from dictionary")
  print(users.dictionaryJson["moreDetails"])
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

The output:

```
    {"age":12,"moreDetails":{"image":"ImageUrl"},"name":"siddhant","topInt":["1","2","3"]}


["topInt": <__NSArrayI 0x6000008e8150>(
1,
2,
3
)
, "name": siddhant, "age": 12, "moreDetails": {
    image = ImageUrl;
}]


Getting the var from dictionary
Optional({
    image = ImageUrl;
})
```

Comment: its not var moreDetails: [MoreDetails] = [MoreDetails(), MoreDetails()]. its var moreDetails = MoreDetails() single not array

Comment: if you see { image = ImageUrl;} is not getting converted to Json If it would be Json so it would be {"image":"ImageUrl"}

Comment: @Swifty again json is your `sid` data object. you just need to initialise a new string with it

Comment: Sorry, you expected output before your post being edited was an array of more details.

Comment: thanks for helping if u find a way to get Required output so please let me know bit new to swift Codable